# How to use jQuery on generated content

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery to create HTML elements (specifically, to add a row to a table), but I want to use the generated elements in jQuery. What I came up myself is this:

```
function add_row() {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);

    $("#properties").append('<tr>'+
        '<td><input id="'+id+'" type="text" name="myInput"></td>'+
    "</tr>");

    $("#"+id).bind('keydown', hotkey.toLowerCase(), function() {
        do_stuff();
    });
}
```

Note that I use https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys to bind to the input. It doesn't seem to support the `on` way.

But this feels a little clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: add a class on the input & then use the http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @AgamBanga wouldn't that bind the `on` multiple times if I call this function more than once?

Comment: use the code outside the method.

Comment: @AgamBanga I can't use it before, because it doesn't exist yet. I have to run the bind on each addition, because the rows are added on a button click.

Comment: Yes thats the beauty of `on` method, it works for dynamic elements as well. You don't need to bind everytime

Comment: For dynamic elements use $(document).on('click', '#id' function() {})